# Get Sympy to expand a fraction into a polynomial equation

Tags: python, sympy

I was wondering how to get Sympy to expand equations with fraction into polynomials. For example, consider the following code

```
from sympy import *
var('x a b c d e')
Eq(a, ()/())
frac = Eq(a, (x + b/x)/(c/x + d/x**2))
pprint(frac)
```

How can I get a polynomial in x? In this case, for example, the polynomial would look something like

```
C1*x**3 + C2*x**2 + C3*x + C4 = 0
```

I've `.as_poly()`, `as_powers_dict()`, `expand()` and some others but I'm pretty much guessing by the name and trying everything that seems remotely possible. Is there a way to do that?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how general this approach will be, but something like this might be useful in some cases:

```
In [299]: frac = Eq(a, (x + b/x)/(c/x + d/x**2))

In [300]: f = factor(frac.lhs - frac.rhs)

In [301]: f
Out[301]: -(-a*c*x - a*d + b*x + x**3)/(c*x + d)

In [302]: f *= denom(f)

In [303]: poly(f, x)
Out[303]: Poly(-x**3 + (a*c - b)*x + a*d, x, domain='ZZ[a,b,c,d]')

In [304]: poly(f, x).as_dict()
Out[304]: {(0,): a*d, (1,): a*c - b, (3,): -1}
```